# gmailr package doesn't retrieve email body when email contains an attachment

Tags: r, gmail

thanks for your time.

I have a specific question related to the gmailr package, by Jim Hester.

From what I can tell, the package maintenance seems to have been abandoned the past couple of years, but the package itself still seems to be in regular use.  With that being said, I've come to learn it can be a little buggy.

I have a question related to the `body` function.  This function should read the body of an email message into R.

For example, this piping of code can be used to return the body of an email, when given the email ID.

```
"1871e8b0d6db9ef88" %>%         # example email message ID
  message() %>%                 # recognized the message from the ID
  body()                        # retrieve the email body
```

The above code works fine, except when the original email message contains an attachment.  When that is the case, the above returns an empty list.  Ideally, the function behavior would be such that the email attachment is ignored, and the email body is returned.

Has anyone been able to find a workout or a solution to this issue when an email attachment is present?

As a reference, it appears similar to this Github issue, but not exactly similar:

https://github.com/jimhester/gmailr/issues/48

Thanks for your time - any insight is appreciated.